# Why am I getting a runtime error on LeetCode submision part though my code is actually running on local softwares like vs code

Tags: python

I have created a program for a problem on LeetCode and it actually works on any Python code editor. But when I run it on the LeetCode submission portion, it shows a runtime error.

Code:

```py
def sol(nums,target):
    
    if (len(nums)<=10**4 and len(nums)>=2) and (target<=10**9 and target>=-10**9):
        soln=[]
        for i in range((len(nums))-1):
            if (nums[i]<=10**9 and nums[i]>=-10**9) and (nums[i+1]<=10**9 and nums[i+1]>=-10**9) :
                if nums[i]+nums[i+1]==target:
                    if i not in soln:
                        soln.append(i)
                        soln.append(i+1)
            else:
                print("Input is not under valid type of data")
                break
        print(soln)
    else:
        print("Input is not under valid type of data")
        
print("Test cases")
print("\nCase 1:") 

nums=[2,7,11,15]
target=9
sol(nums,target)
print("\nCase 2:")
nums=[3,2,4]
target=6
sol(nums,target)
print("\nCase 3:")
nums=[3,3]
target=6
sol(nums,target)
```

Error:

```py
Runtime Error
NameError: global name 'Solution' is not defined
    ret = Solution().twoSum(param_1, param_2)
Line 64 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 74 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: Could you remove the bold text from your entire post?

Comment: Where did you define Solution at then?

Comment: Leetcode seems to want you to write a class called `Solution` with a method `twoSum()`. It usually gives you a minimal script when you first read the question.

Comment: Is your file supposed to by named 'Solution.py' and your function supposed to be named 'twoSum'?

Comment: @JesseSealand: On Leetcode you enter code on a Web UI. Leetcode then creates a file on its own servers where it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to be a method of the `Solution` class:

```py
class Solution:
    def sol(nums, target):
        # your code
```

Furthermore the method name should be `twoSum` not `sol`.

You also need to `return` the result of your function, not `print` it.

Answer (score -1):

leetcode wants the class as a Solution, and then create a function as `sol(nums,target)`